# Which three people can defeat Jaime?

Tags: game-of-thrones, a-song-of-ice-and-fire

In a Game of Thrones episode, when Brienne is taking Jaime back to King's Landing, Jaime quotes that there are "only three people in Westros who can defeat him in a fair duel".However he never mentions their name.
Who are these people.Are they named in the books?(I have not read the books yet I am still watching the show.)

Answer (score 1):

Jaime mentions three men whom he considers his mentors:

> "I learned from **the White Bull and Barristan the Bold**," Jaime
>   snapped. "**I learned from Ser Arthur Dayne**, the Sword of the
>   Morning, who could have slain all five of you with his left hand while
>   he was taking with a piss with the right."
> <sub>**ASOS: Jaime VIII**</sub>

So those three are:

1. Ser Gerold Hightower, the White Bull
2. Ser Barristan Selmy, the Bold
3. Ser Arthur Dayne, Sword of the Morning

But then Jaime mentions that he could have beaten two of them along with Cleganes, Strongboar, Robert, Great Jon:

> The realization chilled him. Robert had been stronger than him, to be
>   sure. The White Bull Gerold Hightower as well, in his heyday, and Ser
>   Arthur Dayne. Amongst the living, Greatjon Umber was stronger,
>   Strongboar of Crakehall most likely, both Cleganes for a certainty.
>   The Mountain’s strength was like nothing human. **It did not matter.
>   With speed and skill, Jaime could beat them all.**
> <sub>**ASOS: Jaime VIII**</sub>

He does not mention Ser Barristan Selmy. So at least one person he thinks could defeat him would be Ser Barristan. The other two are unknown.

Answer (score 0):

I have directly copied the answer from [this](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/11732/who-are-the-three-people-who-could-match-jaime-lannister) movies and tv stackexchange answer.

**Since Jaime himself has yet to reveal who those three are, we simply don't know.**

In the books Jaime idolized **Ser Barristan "The Bold" Selmy** (the Lord Commander of the Kingsguard at the beginning of the series) and has always spoke in admiration of his swordsmanship, so it's safe to assume that he's on the list. Other than that it's pure speculation. Among the living the **Clegane brothers (Sandor the Hound and Gregor the Mountain)** are often described as powerful warriors even by Jaime, so they might be the other two. There are many others, but they are either dead (Ser Arthur "Sword of the Morning" Dayne) or not included in the series (Ser Garlan Tyrell).

There are some arguments that Oberyn Martell might be one of the three people, but as [83457](https://movies.stackexchange.com/users/11511/83457) points out [here](https://movies.stackexchange.com/a/56919/56681), many people outside of Dorne wouldn't have been aware of Oberyn's prowess in fighting.

Comment: Worth noting that this isn't mentioned in the book. I also suggest updating this answer as Oberyn Martell certainly has featured in the show.

Comment: Jaime mentioned in the books that he could take on both Clegane brothers and still win